# Issue with IIS web app manage task - always thinks there are changes to site object

Tags: iis, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to create a site on ISS on one of our machines. The task keeps thinking that the site object changes, even though no changes occurred.

If IIS has no sites, deployment works fine.

```
2023-12-07T09:35:57.7693529Z ##[section]Starting: Ensure speedadmin.dk exists
2023-12-07T09:35:57.8140181Z ==============================================================================
2023-12-07T09:35:57.8140593Z Task         : IIS web app manage
2023-12-07T09:35:57.8140779Z Description  : Create or update websites, web apps, virtual directories, or application pools
2023-12-07T09:35:57.8140909Z Version      : 0.198.0
2023-12-07T09:35:57.8141078Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-12-07T09:35:57.8141248Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group
2023-12-07T09:35:57.8141374Z ==============================================================================
2023-12-07T09:35:58.7649910Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list apppool /name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk"
2023-12-07T09:35:58.8069878Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set apppool /apppool.name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" -managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0 -managedPipelineMode:Integrated -processModel.identityType:NetworkService
2023-12-07T09:35:58.8629729Z APPPOOL object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk" changed
2023-12-07T09:35:58.8695365Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list site /name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk"
2023-12-07T09:35:58.9114872Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  add site /name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" /physicalPath:"D:\speedadmin\websites\prod-a\www.speedadmin.dk"
2023-12-07T09:35:58.9735551Z SITE object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk" added
2023-12-07T09:35:58.9735878Z APP object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk/" added
2023-12-07T09:35:58.9736067Z VDIR object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk/" added
2023-12-07T09:35:58.9837187Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" -applicationDefaults.applicationPool:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" -[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:"D:\speedadmin\websites\prod-a\www.speedadmin.dk" -[path='/'].[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].[path='/'].password:
2023-12-07T09:35:59.0528195Z SITE object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk" changed
2023-12-07T09:35:59.0678012Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list sites
2023-12-07T09:35:59.1225210Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='10.200.36.20:80:']
2023-12-07T09:35:59.1900561Z SITE object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk" changed
2023-12-07T09:35:59.1958739Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list sites
2023-12-07T09:35:59.2354584Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:']
2023-12-07T09:35:59.2924492Z SITE object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk" changed
2023-12-07T09:35:59.2973340Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list sites
2023-12-07T09:35:59.3377913Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='10.200.36.20:443:']
2023-12-07T09:35:59.3959136Z SITE object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk" changed
2023-12-07T09:35:59.4098275Z ##[command]"netsh" http show sslcert ipport=10.200.36.20:443
2023-12-07T09:35:59.4526745Z ##[command]"netsh" http add sslcert ipport=10.200.36.20:443 certhash=*** appid={0d6bcddc-160c-4a7e-9109-5d4268433956} certstorename=MY
2023-12-07T09:35:59.4895986Z 
2023-12-07T09:35:59.4896413Z SSL Certificate successfully added
2023-12-07T09:35:59.5156955Z 
2023-12-07T09:35:59.5157533Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config /section:applicationPools -[name='prod-a.speedadmin.dk'].startMode:AlwaysRunning
2023-12-07T09:35:59.5899922Z Applied configuration changes to section "system.applicationHost/applicationPools" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
2023-12-07T09:35:59.6189008Z ##[section]Finishing: Ensure speedadmin.dk exists
```

Second run of the release fails, even though I have not changed anything about the site or the deployment script.

```
2023-12-07T09:37:09.8796578Z ##[section]Starting: Ensure speedadmin.dk exists
2023-12-07T09:37:09.9264703Z ==============================================================================
2023-12-07T09:37:09.9265143Z Task         : IIS web app manage
2023-12-07T09:37:09.9265330Z Description  : Create or update websites, web apps, virtual directories, or application pools
2023-12-07T09:37:09.9265474Z Version      : 0.198.0
2023-12-07T09:37:09.9265648Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-12-07T09:37:09.9265814Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group
2023-12-07T09:37:09.9265927Z ==============================================================================
2023-12-07T09:37:10.8776860Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list apppool /name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk"
2023-12-07T09:37:10.9211992Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set apppool /apppool.name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" -managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0 -managedPipelineMode:Integrated -processModel.identityType:NetworkService
2023-12-07T09:37:10.9795257Z APPPOOL object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk" changed
2023-12-07T09:37:10.9860198Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list site /name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk"
2023-12-07T09:37:11.0369832Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" -applicationDefaults.applicationPool:"prod-a.speedadmin.dk" -[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:"D:\speedadmin\websites\prod-a\www.speedadmin.dk" -[path='/'].[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].[path='/'].password:
2023-12-07T09:37:11.1063363Z SITE object "prod-a.speedadmin.dk" changed
2023-12-07T09:37:11.1212169Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list sites
2023-12-07T09:37:11.1765311Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list sites
2023-12-07T09:37:11.2176552Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list sites
2023-12-07T09:37:11.2695373Z ##[command]"netsh" http show sslcert ipport=10.200.36.20:443
2023-12-07T09:37:11.3123572Z ##[command]"netsh" http add sslcert ipport=10.200.36.20:443 certhash=*** appid={8e2de72e-4c25-4e53-ac4a-d62bd506e522} certstorename=MY
2023-12-07T09:37:11.3498120Z 
2023-12-07T09:37:11.3498463Z SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183
2023-12-07T09:37:11.3499049Z Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
2023-12-07T09:37:11.3499891Z 
2023-12-07T09:37:11.3499933Z 
2023-12-07T09:37:11.4604555Z ##[error]Process 'netsh' exited with code '1'.
2023-12-07T09:37:11.4803066Z ##[section]Finishing: Ensure speedadmin.dk exists
```

According to the script, it thinks that the site changed. But even if the deployment parameters changed, I don't think that it should fail since the bindings are not used by any other site.

IIS is empty - there are no other sites on it.

Configuration looks like so:
[image]

Variables look like so:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems is a known issue for IIS web app manage task. See below tickets:

- [SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183 Cannot create a file when that file already exists](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/issues/919)
- [IISWebAppMgmt@3 - Windows 2022 - SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183 Cannot create a file when that file already exists](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IISWebAppMgmt3---SSL-Certificate-add-fa/10371316)

From the second ticket, looks like, this issue had been reported to the engineer team for fix. However, there is no update from the engineer team currently.

---

As workaround currently, you can try to add a [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to execute below command before the IIS web app manage task in your pipeline.

This command will remove the certificate added in the previous run.

```
netsh http delete sslcert hostnameport={siteUrl}:443
```

---

Comment: Do I need to check if the cert exists first? Will the command fail if it doesn't?

Comment: @EricRuder, You can try to use the command '[**`netsh http show sslcert`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/show-sslcert)' to list the certificates.